# Reduce Node List by X

Tags: php, web-crawler, goutte

I am currently returning a crawler object with 21 nodes.

```
$crawler->filter('ul.class')->each(function ($node) {         

$lis = $node->children(); // 21 nodes
```

However, the issue I have is, I do not want the first 4 of those nodes. How can I filter the resulting object to only contain the final 17 nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the reduce call.

```
$crawler
    ->filter('ul.class')
    ->reduce(function (Crawler $node, $i) { return $i>=4; })
    ->each(function ($node) { ....
```

That should do the trick